# Application failed after spring boot upgrade to 2.7.x Error executing DDL

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, h2

After upgrading spring boot from version **2.6.3** to **2.7.3**, I have a problem with the H2 database (after the spring boot upgrade, apparently the h2 database also got an upgrade).

After launching the application I get **Error**:

```
GenerationTarget encountered exception accepting command : Error executing DDL "create table appa_attributes (id bigint generated by default as identity, name varchar(255), value varchar(4000), primary key (id))" via JDBC Statement org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL "create table appa_attributes (id bigint generated by default as identity, name varchar(255), value varchar(4000), primary key (id))" via JDBC Statement
```

**application.properties:**

```
server.port=8080
spring.mvc.favicon.enabled = false // this in version 2.7 is deprecated
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.h2.console.path=/console/
spring.h2.console.settings.web-allow-others=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
```

**Attribute.java** (this is how the table is defined)

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "appa_attributes")
public class Attribute extends AbstractEntity<Long> implements Comparable<Attribute> {

    @Column(length = 255)
    private String name;

    @Column(length = 4000)
    private String value;

//getters and setter
```

Comment: `VALUE` is a reserved word in the SQL Standard and is a keyword in new versions of H2. It cannot be used as unquoted identifier.

Comment: @EvgenijRyazanov Thanks for your reply, is it possible to somehow "exclude" this word so that it is not a keyword through, for example, annotations or in some other way, or do you think that a simpler and better way is to change this name after all?

Answer (score 1):

The best choice here is to rename the column with something like `@Column(name = "ATT_VALUE", length = 4000)`, you don't need to rename your field in entity.

Alternatively you can force quotation of all identifiers by setting `hibernate.globally_quoted_identifiers` to `true` (in the Spring configuration it will be `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.globally_quoted_identifiers=true`).

In the worst case you can add `;NON_KEYWORDS=USER` to JDBC URL of H2, but you should understand that this setting isn't very reliable and may not work in all cases.